# How to start mining

Tags: miner-configuration, mining-profitability, mining-hardware

I'm new to cyrptocurrency and heard that gpu's are obsolete for bitcoin mining and I hear gridcoin is a good alternative. How do I start mining? And how long long until I start to break even? Also, I have no idea how to use bitcoin calculators because I don't know the terminoligy. Can someone break this down http://pool.gridcoin.us/ProfitabilityCalculator.aspx

Specs:
R9 390
6700k
725w PSU

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't other mining at all. Mining anything is either unprofitable or will be as more and more people catch on.

If you really are determined to mine, however, a gpu/cpu only coin like gridcoin would be good.

A good general tutorial can be found [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2151261/beginners-guide-to-mining-litecoin-dogecoin-and-other-bitcoin-variants.html). It's not very detailed, but it will suffice.